# Adding data to data row of database in c#

Tags: c#, dataset, connection-string, sqlconnection, datarow

I am facing a little problem in my code to add data to sql database attached with my program in ASP.net/C#. Here's code:

```
string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection"].ConnectionString;


            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select Id from  TableName";
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, " TableName ");
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            DataRow drow =  ds.Tables["TableName"].NewRow();
drow["Id"] = TextBox1.Text;
ds.Tables["TableName "].Rows.Add(drow);

            da.Update(ds, " TableName ");
            string script = @"<script language=""javascript"">
        alert('Information have been Saved Successfully.......!!!!!.');
       </script>;";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);
```

---

Even when I entered any integer value to the text box, it shows an error message that object is not set to an instance on code:

```
DataRow drow =  ds.Tables["TableName"].NewRow();
```

Please guide.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very bad way of inserting data. Have you looked at the [Entity Framework](http://entityframeworktutorial.net/) or [Linq2Sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)? Alternatively you could just use a standard SqlCommand and set the CommandText yourself.

Any of these would provide a cleaner solution.

Eg: With ADO.NET (Connecting to SQLite):

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(Constants.SQLiteConnectionString, "db.db3"));
conn.Open();
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableName (Id) VALUES (@Id)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", someTextVariable);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for answering. By the way, can you show me your way of data insertion please. I am not insisting on this way but if you understand what I mean to do, you may provide with your own manner here.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd use a combination of the code sample I've added and the Entity Framework. The reason I don't use the Entity Framework for inserts is because I find it tends to get easily confused by complex object graphs.